# What is the use of hyperbolic trigonometric functions if they are easily expressible algebraically?

Tags: hyperbolic-functions

I get that there are uses for $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ because they are defined with imaginary exponents which aren't as easily worked with but the hyperbolic functions are simply $\frac12(e^x\pm e^{-x})$. I don't see why it would be necessary to define a function to represent this. It is almost like defining a function to represent the value of $2$.

The only other time I can think of where there is a "useless" function is for pedagogical purposes such as the identity function.

Comment: They have particular uses in a lot of areas including hyperbolic geometry. You should look things up before calling functions "useless" that are quite useful. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function

Comment: The identity is not useless, it's the identity. It's useful to name it because it's used all the time. As for your question, do you know about complex trigonometric functions?

Comment: It's shorthand.  Imagine having to write that over and over, especially when you need to divide one by the other or combine them in some other way.  Would you rather see $tanh(x)$, or a mess of exponential functions everywhere?

Comment: @KajHansen I think you missed the point of the question. You can introduce an abbreviation for $x\mapsto 2x+3-\sin(x)$, but you don't do it. The question is "Why is it worth it to introduce this notation for these functions?"

Comment: Ah, the useless identity function. Throw it away, together with all those useless identity elements of groups.

Comment: You might also note that $\sin x = \tfrac{1}{2i}(e^{ix} - e^{-ix})$ and $\cos x = \tfrac12 (e^{ix} + e^{-ix})$. So the standard trigonometric functions are also expressible algebraically, almost as simply as the hyperbolic functions.

Comment: There *is* a function to represent the value $2$. We usually write it(s evaluation) as $2$.

Answer (score 2):

In the same way that the point $(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$ is on the circle, the point $(\cosh\theta, \sinh\theta)$ is on a hyperbola (hence the hyperbolic part). They show up all the time in solutions to the heat equation, and a hanging rope is actually a hyperbolic cosine function. Many many reasons why we would want to have a notation for it.

Answer (score 2):

$\cos(\theta)$ and $\sin(\theta)$ are essential for understanding geometry on the sphere, as ocean navigators have known for a couple of millennia. $\cosh(t)$ and $\sinh(t)$ are similarly essential for understanding geometry on the hyperbolic plane.

Answer (score 2):

consider $y''+y=0$ with initial conditions $y(0)=0,y'(0)=1$ and $y(0)=1, y'(0)=1$.  the solutions are $\sin x$ and $\cos x$.

similarly, $y''-y=0$ with initial conditions $y(0)=0,y'(0)=1$ and $y(0)=1, y'(0)=1$ give $\sinh x$ and $\cosh x$.

(transcendental solutions of differential equations often get names when they are used often: $e^x$, bessel functions, weierstrass $\wp$, etc.)

just as $x=\cos t, y=\sin t$ gives a unit speed parameterization of the unit circle, $x=\cosh t, y=\sinh t$ gives a 'unit speed' parameterization of the unit hyperbola.

Answer (score 1):

But $\sin x = \frac{\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}x} - \mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}x}}{2\mathrm{i}}$ and $\cos x = \frac{\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}x} + \mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}x}}{2}$.  So we don't need sine or cosine either.

The hyperbolic functions **are** handy for computing sine and cosine with complex arguments... \begin{align*}
\sin(x+\mathrm{i}y) &= \sin x \cosh y + \mathrm{i} \cos x \sinh y \\
\cos(x+\mathrm{i}y) &= \cos x \cosh y - \mathrm{i} \sin x \sinh y
\end{align*}